# Add filename as header while merging csv files

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv

Want to combine all csv in one folder. This works as intended.

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd

extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]

#combine all files in the list
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames], axis = 1)
#export to csv
combined_csv.to_csv( "combined.matrix", index=False)
```

However I would to add the filename without extension as header.

File1.csv

```
A,B
1,2
3,4
```

File2.csv

```
A,B
5,6
```

combined.matrix

```
File1,File1,File2,File2
A,B,A,B
1,2,5,6
3,4,,
```

Comment: What about `combined_csv.columns = all_filenames` before export?

Comment: As new to Python and willing to learn ;) ... what do you mean exactly?

Comment: Have added an answer with some explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code:

```
import pandas as pd

all_filenames = ['File1.csv','File2.csv']
headers = []
for i in all_filenames:
    headers.append(i.replace('.csv', ''))

combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames], keys=headers, axis = 1)
```

Created a header list with file names excluding the extension. Pass the list to keys argument in pd.concat function.

Answer (score 0):

```py
import os
import pandas as pd

parent_dir = 'YOUR_PARENT_DIRECTORY_PATH'
ext = 'csv'

combined_csv = pd.DataFrame()

for root, dir, files in os.walk(parent_dir):
    for f in files:
        path = os.path.join(root, f)
        filename, extension = os.path.splitext(f)
        if extension == f'.{ext}':
            new_df = pd.read_csv(path)
            cols = new_df.columns
            new_cols = []
            for c in cols:
                new_cols.append(f'{filename}{c}')
            new_df.columns = new_cols
            combined_csv = pd.concat([combined_csv, new_df], axis=1)

combined_csv.to_csv( "combined.matrix", index=False)
```

Comment: new_cols = new_cols.append(f'{filename}{c}') causes 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'. Changed it to new_cols.append(f'{filename}{c}') like suggested here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894795/appending-list-but-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-append

Comment: However combined.csv has File1A,File1B,File2A,File2B as header

Comment: My apologies, yes, the ```list.append()``` method should be returning None, which would cause problems. I corrected my answer above. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea being that you can include the file names somewhere in the `DataFrame` itself (in this case I am including it in the column names, you could probably include them in a row as well) as you are anyway exporting it to csv for further processing

```
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
# This takes the value ["file1.csv", "file2.csv"]

#combine all files in the list
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_filenames], axis = 1)
# This looks like
# A B A B
# 1 2 5 6
# 3 4 nan nan
```

As the column names are fixed (A and B) - and you are more interested in the file names, you can change the columns with

```
combined_csv.columns = sorted(all_filenames * len(combined_csv.columns) / len(all_filenames))
# This evaluates to sorted(["file1.csv", "file2.csv"] * 4 / 2) which is equal to ["file1.csv", "file1.csv", "file2.csv", "file2.csv"]
```

And now your dataframe would look like - which indicates which column is from which file

```
# file1.csv file1.csv file2.csv file2.csv
# 1 2 5 6
# 3 4 nan nan
```

Which you can export to the `combined.matrix.csv`