# Error plz help i am getting attribute error even when I have specified the datatype as list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, attributeerror

This is my function-

```
def subsets(inp,out,index):
    if index >= len(inp):
        print(out)
        return 
    subsets(inp,out,index+1)
    subsets(inp,out.append(inp[index]), index +1)
subsets([1,2,3],[],0)
```

and this is the error that i am getting

```
subsets(inp,out.append(inp[index]), index +1)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append'
```

I dont know why I am getting this error when I have given the value of output as []

Comment: ```out.append(inp[index])``` returns a None..  so you're essentially doing ```subsets(inp, None, index + 1)```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do these list operations (methods: clear / extend / reverse / append / sort / remove) return None, rather than the resulting list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11205254/why-do-these-list-operations-methods-clear-extend-reverse-append-sort)

Answer (score 0):

This problem when you use this :

```
subsets(inp,out.append(inp[index]), index +1)
```

it means:

```
out = out.append(inp[index])
```

You must change as follows:

```
out.append(inp[index]
```

then your code :

```
def subsets(inp,out,index):
    if index >= len(inp):
        print(out)
        return
    out.append(inp[index])
    subsets(inp, out, index+1)
subsets([1,2,3],[1],0)
```

For more  go to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12894795/appending-list-but-error-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-append)